# How to setup native remote debugging?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, native, remote-debugging

Everytime I try to setup remote debugging it always results in a world of hurt. What do I need to do, in order to debug my MFC application on a remote machine? I'm using Windows 7, the VM is using Windows XP.

I've got msvsmon running on the remote computer, and I've connected successfully, but the problem I'm having is the VM can't launch my debug exe because it says:

> This application has failed to start
>   because the application configuration
>   is incorrect. Reinstalling the
>   application may fix this problem
>   (14001).

I've installed the VC Runtime Redist, I've copied the MFC / CRT non-redist debug files onto the VM (and into the same directory as the program). I've tried following the advice of editing the manifest file's version information from this blog post - http://qualapps.blogspot.com/2008/07/visual-studio-2008-c-redistributable.html. But nothing seems to be able to get it to work.

I've inspected MyAppD.exe using Dependancy Walker and it gives me the same error (about side-by-side assemblies plus the text above).

Does anyone have a fool-proof method for getting this stuff working (on a clean VM)?

Comment: If memory serves, getting this to work for me in the past was akin to having someone stamp repeatedly on my testicles.  Your mileage may (hopefully) vary :)

Comment: Can you specify which library gives the SxS error in Dependency Walker?

Comment: @Moo-Juice, that's exactly what I'm finding now... @Frederic, all of my libraries are failing to load in debug builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just haven't been able to solve this successfully. The only work around I have is to install the same version of Visual Studio that I use, and that installs and configures everything I need for remote debugging. It's a massive overkill, but it does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is probably that you're using a debug build of your application, but you've installed the release C++ runtime. You actually need to have the debug C++ runtimes installed on the remote machine in order to run a debug application on it.

Since MSVC 2005, the C++ runtimes have been side-by-side assemblies which makes installing them a little more complex than it used to be (time was you could just copy the msvcrt71d.dll etc across). I wrote a blog article about my experience setting it up a few years ago (with 2005), and I believe that the same principle still applies.

http://www.stevestreeting.com/2007/10/25/remote-debugging-tips/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Steve, I was excited to see your suggestions, but unfortunately I tried both and I still can't get it to work :(.

Comment: I even tried adding the Policy 9.0 merge modules (see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/867cf808-bf1f-4f4a-bde1-cd75d92d73ad) and it wouldn't work.

Comment: Hmm. I'm still pretty sure that lack of the Debug runtimes is the root of this. One complication is that MS has released version updates to the CRT as part of service packs or hotfixes occasionally - this caused me no end of problems the last time they did it.

Comment: Check the .manifest file that is built in the same folder as your debug executable (it's embedded in the exe or dlls as part of the build process but the separate file is easier to read). Check the version numbers of the CRT carefully, then check whether you have those specific versions in WinSxS on the remote machine.

Comment: Oh, and that article you linked was about the *release* versions of the merge modules, so if version mismatch is the issue you actually need to find the *debug* merge modules on your machine; they're only there because you have VC++ installed. The correct ones will look like microsoft_vcNN_debugcrt_x86.msm